# Why site:example.com doesn't give the same amount of results in incognito mode

Tags: google, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, search-results, google-index

Did you ever tried to search on Google site:domain.example on incognito mode? I am never getting the same amount of results than when I am doing it in normal mode. Sometimes more, sometimes less, do you have an explanation for this?

**Here my example:**

By searching "site:blackmaki.fr" on Google + Chrome, I am getting 116 results.

[image]

By searching "site:blackmaki.fr" on Google + Incognito Chrome, I am getting 48 results.

[image]

Comment: What are some examples of pages that are not shown in incognito?

Answer (score 2):

Result counts from Google are estimates.  Google says they are not consistent or accurate.  Furthermore, `site:` searches don't show everything from a site.

You shouldn't be trying to use `site:` search results to get accurate info about a site.  If it is your own site, you should sign up for Google Search Console instead.

For what it's worth, I get the same number of results in incognito and normal modes, but the number doesn't match either of your numbers.

[image]